# Topological groups - Actions and Hausdorffness

Tags: topological-groups

I guess this problem is widely-known, but I couldn't finish it.

If $X$ is a topological group (and compact), and $G$ a closed subgroup acting on $X$ by left translation, show that $X/G$ is Hausdorff.

I was trying to use that famous lemma about an equivalence relation on $X$ being open, but I couldn't do it yet. Is this the way? Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lemma 1**
Let $f\colon X \rightarrow X'$ and $g\colon Y \rightarrow Y'$ be open maps of topological spaces.
Then $f\times g \colon X\times Y \rightarrow X'\times Y'$ is open.

Proof:
Clear.

**Lemma 2**
Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces.
Let $R$(resp. $S$) be an equivalence relation on $X$(resp. $Y$).
Suppose the canonical map  $X \rightarrow X/R$(resp. $Y \rightarrow Y/S$) is open.
Let $R\otimes S$ be the equivalence relation on $X\times Y$ such that $(x, y) \equiv (x', y')$ (mod $R\otimes S)$ if and only $x \equiv x'$ (mod $R)$ and $y \equiv y'$ (mod $S)$.
Then the canonical map $(X\times Y)/(R\otimes S) \rightarrow (X/R)\times (Y/S)$ is an isomorphism.

Proof:
Let $f\colon X\times Y \rightarrow (X/R)\times (Y/S)$ be the canonical map.
By Lemma 1, $f$ is open.
Hence $f$ induces an isomorphism $(X\times Y)/(R\otimes S) \rightarrow (X/R)\times (Y/S)$.
**QED**

**Lemma 3**
Le $X$ be a topological space.
Let $\Delta$ be the diagonal of $X\times X$, i.e, $\Delta = \{(x, x) \in X \times X\colon x \in X\}$.
Then $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if $\Delta$ is closed.

Proof:
Left to the readers.

**Lemma 4**
Le $X$ be a topological space.
Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on $X$.
Suppose the canonical map $X \rightarrow X/R$ is open.
Let $C$ be the graph of $R$, i.e. $C = \{(x, y) \in X\times X\colon x \equiv y$ (mod $R)\}$.
Suppose $C$ is closed.
Then $X/R$ is Hausdorff.

Proof:
Let $f\colon X\times X \rightarrow (X/R)\times (X/R)$ be the canonical map.
By Lemma 2, $f$ induces an isomorphism $(X\times X)/(R \otimes R) \rightarrow (X/R)\times (X/R)$.
Let $\Delta$ be the diagonal of $(X/R)\times (X/R)$.
Since $f^{-1}(\Delta) = C$, $\Delta$ is closed.
Hence $X/R$ is Hausdorff by Lemma 3.
**QED**

**Proposition**
Let $X$ be a topological group.
Let $G$ be a closed subgroup of $X$.
Let $X/G$ be the space of left cosets of $X$ by $G$.
Then $X/G$ is Hausdorff.

Proof:
Let $R$ be the equivalence relation on $X$ defined by $x \equiv y$ (mod $R)$ if and if $x^{-1}y \in G$.
Then $X/G = X/R$.
Let $C$ be the graph of $R$.
Let $f\colon X\times X \rightarrow X$ be the map definded by $f(x, y) = x^{-1}y$.
Then $f$ is continuous and $f^{-1}(G) = C$.
Since $G$ is closed, $C$ is closed.
Clearly the canonical map $X \rightarrow X/G$ is open.
Hence $X/G$ is Hausdorff by Lemma 4.
**QED**

Comment: The relation that $R$ and $S$ naturally induce on $X\times Y$ isn’t actually $R\times S$: it’s $$\left\{\big\langle\langle x_0,y_0\rangle,\langle x_1,y_1\rangle\big\rangle:\big\langle\langle x_0,x_1\rangle,\langle y_0,y_1\rangle\big\rangle\in R\times S\right\}\;.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks. I corrected the answer.

Comment: The following lemma may make the proof of Lemma 4 clearer.

**Lemma 1.5**
Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a surjective open map of topological spaces.
Let $U, F$ be subests of $Y$.
Then

If $f^{-1}(U)$ is open, $U$ is open.

If $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed, $F$ is closed.

Proof:
Suppose $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.
Since $f$ is surjective $f(f^{-1}(U)) = U$.
Since $f$ is open, $U$ is open.

Suppose $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed.
Since $X - f^{-1}(F) = f^{-1}(Y - F)$ is open, $Y - F$ is open by the above.
Hence $F$ is closed
**QED**

Comment: I read this proof a dozen times and I really can't find any problem with it.  But it bothers me that the OP said $X$ is compact yet that was never used - particularly because this is exercise 30 (of section 4.4) of Armstrong Basic Topology and he also assumes $X$ is compact.